# Как отсортировать таблицу с перечнем одинаковых значений по убыванию?

Tags: excel

Имеется колонка в Excel с повторяющимися значениями, приведу их пример (отфильтрованы по алфавитному порядку):

`Samsung Galaxy A
Samsung Galaxy A
Samsung Galaxy A
Samsung Galaxy A
Samsung Galaxy G
Samsung Galaxy G
Samsung Galaxy G
Samsung Galaxy G
Samsung Galaxy G
Samsung Galaxy G
Samsung Galaxy H
Samsung Galaxy S
Samsung Galaxy S
Samsung Galaxy S
Samsung Galaxy S Pro
Samsung Galaxy S Pro
Samsung Galaxy S Pro
Samsung Galaxy S Pro
Samsung Galaxy S Pro`

Далее еще большое количество товаров, это лишь выдержка. В основном одинаковых моделей по 18 подряд.
Как отсортировать так, чтобы они были отфильтрованы по убыванию одинаковых значений?

Например, если брать выше приведенный пример

`(1) Samsung Galaxy G 
(2) Samsung Galaxy G
(3) Samsung Galaxy G
(4) Samsung Galaxy G
(5) Samsung Galaxy G
(6) Samsung Galaxy G

(1) Samsung Galaxy S Pro
(2) Samsung Galaxy S Pro
(3) Samsung Galaxy S Pro
(4) Samsung Galaxy S Pro
(5) Samsung Galaxy S Pro

(1) Samsung Galaxy A
(2) Samsung Galaxy A
(3) Samsung Galaxy A
(4) Samsung Galaxy A

(1) Samsung Galaxy S
(2) Samsung Galaxy S
(3) Samsung Galaxy S

(1) Samsung Galaxy H`

И при этом фильтрация должна быть по этому столбцу (A), а соседние (B, С, D, E ...) быть зависимыми и меняться вместе с ней, но зафиксировано по отношению к нему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Используйте такую формулу, как СЧЕТЕСЛИ, ее можно найти в параметрах формул.**

1) Создайте дополнительный столбец, выделите затем первую часть столбца с одинаковыми значениями.
 
2) В первое значение возьмите первую строку ячейки-доннора - во второе - последнюю. 
Далее - дублируйте, зажав умное выделение. 
3) Сортируйте как душе угодно расширенным фильтром

Answer (score 1):

Пусть в столбце А находятся наименования от A1 до А100.

Добавим справа столбец В и в ячейку В1 введем формулу =СЧЁТЕСЛИ($A$1:$A$100;A1)

Размножим ее на весь столбец. Далее сортируем по 2-м критериям Столбец В по убыванию, столбец А по возрастанию.

Если нужно чтобы было не видно, сделайте подсчет дубликатов правее.